# Why does grep return a partial list of matches, then quits, deeming the rest of the file a binary?

Tags: grep

I have a relatively large file (24M, 173K lines) which I am grepping for a string ("SIM_ANALYTICS").  After correctly finding the first 23 matching lines, it reports "Binary file  matches" and ends there.  If I "grep -a --text", then it works fine, finding 91 matching lines.

For some reason, grep starts out interpreting the file as a text file and finds the first 23.  Then it seems to switch mode and thinks it's a binary file and quits (unless I use -a --text).

I can cat the file to STDOUT, it looks fine.

A simple perl script confirms that the lines found with grep -a --text returns the correct lines (91 of them).

The code that I'm working with greps for the string by back-ticking grep  and sending that output to an array.  It does not look for "Binary file ... matches".  So now I feel that this is not reliable.  grep seems to be unreliable (never thought I'd be saying anything like that !)

Outside of "always use -a --text", any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Please show your actual `grep` command and your simple Perl script.

Comment: `grep` treats binary files differently to avoid outputting unreadable data. The criteria for determining if a file is binary depends on your platform and version of `grep`. If your file contains bytes that aren't recognized as text in your current locale, you may want to use the `-a` option.

Comment: MArk:  It's "grep SIM_ANAYLTICS <filename>".  That's all

Comment: IronMan:  Maybe that's it.  It's a log file and sometimes people like to throw eye candy in them (colored text and whatnot) using escape sequences.  I'll use the -a.